# How to track site search(with query and without) via GTM? 2 ways of searching

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a search bar on my website and there is 2 ways of getting search results

1. When they type keyword in the search bar and they press enter button. They will be redirected to the page with the url address with query. For example: /?s=test - I have this in GA but...
2. In the same time when user is typing keyword he gets search results in real-time via AJAX under search bar in the form of a list

   . When 
   the displayed result is clicked user will be redirected straight to the result page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPwFI.jpg

And I want to know how to track this second option because Google Analytics is not able to collect this type of searching via AJAX.
Google Tag Manager and VirtualPageView? How to do it guys cuz Im a newbie

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX's success callback, you can fire a `virtual pageview` or an `event` with Google Analytics. Since you have used Google tag manager, you can push a dataLayer event

```
success: function(data) { 
  dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'searchEvent',
    'keyword': 'keyword'
  })
```

.........

Then you can use this in GTM to create a trigger and fire an event or a virtual pageview. If you are using Virtual pageview, override your location parameter with something like `/?s={{keyword}}`, where `{{keyword}}` is a dataLayer variable and it would work

Comment: Another way would be to send the keyword as custom dimension and then use a GA filter to copy it to the search term field. I found that a little easier than adding search parameters to urls (since you need to check for existing parameters to see which delimiter to use etc).